# JSON stringify creates underscore when there is a space or non-letter character, why?

Tags: javascript, php, json, stringify, velo

Hello I have a function which is sending data using `POST` method to a server which then I use `PHP` to decode the JSON string. I am using for headers `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` and for the body `JSON.stringify`

What I end up is this string:

> [{"registration":true,"name":"dfsdf","last":"fsfs","email":"fdsfsd@gmail_com","phone":"fdsfds","city":"fsfsd","password":"password"}]
>   =>

Then I use this code `json_decode(key($_POST))` to decode the string and I end up with this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [registration] => 1
    [name] => dfsdf
    [last] => fsfs
    [email] => fdsfsd@gmail_com
    [phone] => fdsfds
    [city] => fsfsd
    [password] => password
)
```

My problem is when there is a space or any other non-letter character like for example in this email address i got an underscore instead. I have send **fdsfsd@gmail.com**, but I end up getting **fdsfsd@gmail_com**. Do you know how to fix that? I am using Wix backed module to send the data by the way if this information is valuable. This is my full code:

```
import {fetch} from 'wix-fetch';

export function registration(name, last, email, phone, city, password) {
    return fetch("https://api.demo.com/auth.php", {
        "method": "post",
        "headers": {
            //   "Content-Type": "application/json"
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        "body": JSON.stringify({
            registration: true,
            name: name,
            last: last,
            email: email,
            phone: phone,
            city: city,
            password: password,
        }),
    }).then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
             return response.text();
            // return response.json();
        } else {
            return Promise.reject("Fetch did not succeed");
        }
    });
}
```

So far I have tried those things, but I always end up with an empty string:

- change the Content-Type to `application/json`
- remove `JSON.stringify` from body
- remove `JSON.stringify` from body and add `application/json`

Comment: Have you tried removing the `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` header?

Comment: Why `x-www-form-urlencoded` when you send JSON?

Comment: @Andreas, because I am getting empty string when I use application/json

Comment: @NigelRen, I just tried that, but I am getting an empty string again

Comment: Perhaps it is your wix-fetch at fault here. Can you debug and check in browser console what is in the request after it is sent, and compare it to what’s arriving on the server? Post it here for us, too.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, I tried using this code `let demo = JSON.stringify({ registration: true, name: name, last: last, email: email, phone: phone, city: city, password: password,});
console.log(demo);` and I get this: `registration:  true name:  "dimo padalaski" last:  "pdalaski" email:  "fdsfdsfdsf@gmail.com" phone:  "fsdfsdf" city:  "fsdfsdf" password:  "password"` which looks OK to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manage to get it done. I had to use this `php://input` and it finally worked. This is the line of code I used:

> $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

and this is the output

```
Array
(
  [registration] => 1
  [name] => dfsdf
  [last] => fsfs
  [email] => fdsfsd@gmail.com
  [phone] => fdsfds
  [city] => fsfsd
  [password] => password
)
```